# Comparing two CSV files and create a new file with the unmatched values

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have two files in CSV, ServiceAccount file, ServiceAccount - Exclusion

```
ServiceAccount File Details

FirstName Surname   LoginName
Andrew    Jones     AJones
Ajay      Singh     ASingh
Bobby     Deol      BDeol
Rony      Choudhury RChoudhury
Tim       Perera    TPerera
```

ServiceAccount - Exclusion

```
FirstName Surname   LoginName
Andrew    Jones     AJones
Bobby     Deol      BDeol
```

New CSV File should be like below

```
FirstName Surname   LoginName
Ajay      Singh     ASingh
Rony      Choudhury RChoudhury
Tim       Perera    TPerera
```

I have written this code but I can't see the above results, can anyone please help here, Below is my code.

```
$Path = "C:\PowerShell"


$ServiceAccountExclusion = "C:\temp\Test\ServiceAccount - Exclusion.csv"
$ServcieAccount = "C:\temp\Test\ServiceAccount.csv"
$UserList = Import-Csv $ServiceAccountExclusion -Delimiter ","
$UserData = Import-Csv $ServcieAccount -Delimiter ","

$UserOutput = @()

    ForEach ($name in $UserData)
    {

        $userMatch = $UserList | where {$_.FirstName -ne $name.FirstName}
        If($userMatch)
        {
            # Process the data

            $UserOutput += New-Object PsObject -Property @{UserName =$name.FirstName}

        }
        
        <# {
            $UserOutput += New-Object PsObject -Property @{UserName =$name.FirstName}
        }  #>
    }
$UserOutput | ft
```

Comment: `$Exclude = (import-csv .\exclusion.csv).FirstName; import-csv .\ServiceAccount |Where-Object FirstName -NotIn $Exclude`

Answer (score 0):

It all depends if you're looking for results to solve a problem, or if you're looking for the absolute best answer to solve this in PowerShell.

In my case, I can offer you a quick and dirty solution going from objects, to strings, and back again if needed

```
(Get-Content 'C:\PS\ServiceAccounts.csv') + (Get-Content 'C:\PS\ServiceAccountsExcluded.csv') | select -Unique | Out-File -FilePath "C:\PS\ServiceAccountsCombined.csv"

$ServiceAccountsCombined = Import-CSV -Path "C:\PS\ServiceAccountsCombined.csv"

$ServiceAccountsCombined
```